# Can't dual boot windows 8 and ubuntu.?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows

I have successfully dual booted ubuntu and windows on my sony vaio laptop. The thing is when i logout of ubuntu and restart the computer,  then boot with windows, the next time i try to boot into ubuntu, i cant. Because grub loader wont show up and laptop directly boots to windows.  Then i have to use by ubuntu burned usb stick to get into "live ubuntu" and boot-repair using "recommended settings". Why is it happening?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try disabling Hybrid Boot and UEFI boot?

http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6320-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-8-a.html
http://itsfoss.com/disable-uefi-secure-boot-in-windows-8/

Comment: Yes i have already. No change